# How to style the output of <jdoc:include type="component" /> within templates?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

is there any way to style the output of `<jdoc:include type="component" />` within the templates without modifying Joomla core function?

Specifically, I would like to add a div with id `article` to include the article and nothing else. By now, in my theme, there's a div with class `item-page` that includes the article, the ratings, the action and even the comment box (added with an external plugin).

So, I would like the new templates to be something like:

```
<div class="item-page>
    <!-- something here -->
    <div id="article">
        <!-- The article and nothing else here -->
    </div>
    <!-- comments and whatever may be here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a layout override.

Go to the `tmpl` folder of the view you want to modify the layout for and copy to the `html` folder of your template ... so say article:
get `/components/views/article/default.php` and copy that to 
`templates/[yourtemplate]/html/com_content/article/default.php`
Modify the file as you wish.

This will default change it on all pages using that template.